# If an abelian group G of order 10 contains an element of order 5,how can i prove that G must be a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that G is a cyclic group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239731/prove-that-g-is-a-cyclic-group)

If an abelian group $G$ of order $10$ contains an element of order $5$ ,how can I prove that $G$ must be a cyclic group.

i am completely stuck on it. can anyone help?

Comment: Do you know the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups yet? I think you can use that to prove that every Abelian group of order 10 is cyclic.

Answer (score 1):

First, prove that any group of even order contains an element of order 2.

Now let $a$ be an element of order 2, let $b$ be an element of order $5$, and contemplate the order of $ab$.